# How to have a calender popup with in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In my iPhone application, I would like to open a calendar on click of a UIButton, from where user would be able to choose a date.
I could not find much material on google.
Help with code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the solutions I could find:

[OCCalendar](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar)

[image]

[PMCalendar](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar)

[image]

[CKCalendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)

[image]

[Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

[image]

[TapKu](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

[image]

Source: [cocoacontrols.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)